# 'php magento setup:di:compile' generated cache file with wrong user groups

Tags: magento2, cache, command-line, file-permissions

Suppose `user-a` run the command `php magento setup:di:compile`, it generated cache file with wrong user group, the wrong user group is `user-a`(the primary group of user-a), in fact it should be `apache`(the apache group in CentOS), then it will result file permission error when visit website in browser.

I had set the `SetGID`, most files generated with right user group(apache), only the files in `var/cache/mage-tags` folder has wrong user group(user-a), so I have to set its group manually every time, anyone has **better way** to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly this same problem. The approach of two users as described on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-private just plain doesn't work! As soon as I compile DI with the Magento system owner ("magento_user"), `var/cache/*` folders lose their set-gid bits, and `var/cache/mage-tags/*` folders are created with magento_user's primary group and 660 permissions, and the web user (www-data) fails opening the site because it cannot access this content.

Comment: @JānisElmeris Yes, exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run magento command with **web server user** will solve a lot of permission problems or potential problems.

```
sudo -u apache php magento setup:upgrade
sudo -u apache php magento setup:di:compile
```

Run the cron jobs also under the **web server user**

```
sudo -u apache crontab -e
```

> **apache** is the web server user in CentOS.
>
> The default web server user of Ubuntu is **www-data**.

Comment: I would see this as a work-around. As the whole point (or much of it, at least) of having two-user set-up is exactly to run console commands with one, and serve web content with the other. Quotes from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html#perms-private (Set ownership and permissions for two users): "Magento file system owner is another term for the command-line user.", "In this type of setup, you typically cannot log in as, or switch to, the web server user. You typically log in as one user and run the web server as a different user."

Comment: @JānisElmeris Yes, it is just a work-around. Another way is change the user primary group as apache, but it is not secure. The better way is official Magento fix the compile problem.

Comment: Reported in their issue tracker: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11930

Comment: @JānisElmeris My English is not very well, thanks for your issue report, I had go to thumb up the report.

Comment: By Magento team in that issue: "The fix will be available with the upcoming 2.2.5 release."